# Code throws error over the specification of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science, feature-selection

I keep receiving the following value error when I run my model:

`ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames`

Here's the full version of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 425, in _get_column_indices
    all_columns = X.columns

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/user/Python Practice/Working/Playstore/untitled0.py", line 48, in <module>
    run.fit(x,y)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 330, in fit
    Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 292, in _fit
    X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 352, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 740, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 529, in fit_transform
    self._validate_remainder(X)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 327, in _validate_remainder
    cols.extend(_get_column_indices(X, columns))

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 427, in _get_column_indices
    raise ValueError("Specifying the columns using strings is only "

ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames
```

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor
from category_encoders import CatBoostEncoder
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv",index_col=("Unnamed: 0"))
y = data.Installs
x = data.drop("Installs",axis=1)


strat = ["mean","median","most_frequent","constant"]
num_imp = SimpleImputer(strategy=strat[0])
obj_imp = SimpleImputer(strategy=strat[2])

# Set up the scaler
sc = StandardScaler()

# Set up Encoders
cb = CatBoostEncoder()
oh = OneHotEncoder(sparse=True)


# Set up columns
obj = list(x.select_dtypes(include="object"))
num = list(x.select_dtypes(exclude="object"))


cb_col = [i for i in obj if len(x[i].unique())>30]
oh_col = [i for i in obj if len(x[i].unique())<10]

# First Pipeline
imp = make_pipeline((num_imp))
enc_cb = make_pipeline((cb),(obj_imp))
enc_oh = make_pipeline((oh),(obj_imp))

# Col Transformation
col = make_column_transformer((imp,num),(sc,num))
cb_ = make_column_transformer((enc_cb,cb_col))
oh_ = make_column_transformer((enc_oh,oh_col))

model = AdaBoostRegressor(random_state=(0))

run = make_pipeline((col),(cb_),(oh_),(model))
run.fit(x,y)
```

Any ideas as to how I can fix it? The data used can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aykQWbMm0k4AjYXZ9O-_etlkogqTuiYh/view?usp=sharing) if you need it. Initially I tried performing all the column transformations in one go under a single transformer variable, but that didn't work and I was advised to separate them before running again. I did that, but with the result you see. I'd like some help please. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not separate the column transformers like this.  This way, in your `run` pipeline, the first `ColumnTransformer` `col` converts the input from a pandas dataframe into a numpy array.  But then the column names aren't around to be picked out by `cb_` (and worse, the column order has changed, so you can't rely on the column indices from the original data).

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64540248/10495893) to another of your questions for what I think is the simplest way to build this pipeline.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up fixing it myself in a manner similar to your advice.

Comment: Can you maybe help me with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71543127/unable-to-make-prediction-after-loading-sklearn-model