# Unable to make prediction after loading sklearn model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have created a ML model with Scikit-Learn and saved it. Now when I load the model, I have trouble with transformation and prediction.
I have 4 features in DataFrame. First two features are textual, and other 2 are numerical. The result column is 1 or 0.

In order to train my model, I used `ColumnTransformer` and `CountVectorizer` for transformation and vectorization textual features. I specified NAMES of the columns that I want to transform/vectorize.
(columns text1 and text2). Numerical columns do not need to be vectorized so `remainder='passthrough'` is fixing that.

Part of code that works:

```
features = df.iloc[:, :-1]
results = df.iloc[:, -1]

transformerVectoriser = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('vector word 1', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 1), max_features = 12000, stop_words = 'english'), 'text1'),
                                                       ('vector phrase 3', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(3, 3), max_features = 2500, stop_words = 'english'), 'text2')],
                                                      remainder='passthrough') # Default is to drop untransformed columns, passthrough == leave columns as they are

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, results, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

x_train = transformerVectoriser.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = transformerVectoriser.transform(x_test)


model = clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

filename = 'ml_model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))

filename = 'ml_transformer.sav'
pickle.dump(transformerVectoriser, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

But when I want to load a model, and make prediction I get an error:

```
# LOADING MODEL
model = pickle.load(open('ml_model.sav','rb'))
vectorizer = pickle.load(open('ml_transformer.sav','rb'))

# MAKING PREDICTION
data_for_prediction = vectorizer.transform([data_for_prediction]) #ERROR
print(model.predict_proba(data_for_prediction))
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames
```

When I was training my model I used `Pandas` dataframe, and when I wanted to make prediction I have just put the values in the list. So `data_for_prediction` is list, that looks like this:

```
["text that should be vectorized with vectorizer that i created", "More texts that should be vectorized", 4, 7]
```

I think that that is the error, Because I used column names when I was using ColumnTransformer, but now when I want to make prediction, vectorizer do not know what to vectorize.
My final model and vectorizer should be used in an API, and api should only take JSON, so I do not want to convert JSON to DataFrame and pass it to the model.
Is there a way to fix this error without using pandas `dataframe` in my final Flask APP.

Comment: What happens if you try `features = df.iloc[:, :-1].values` instead?  This won't propagate `feature_names`, but maybe that's OK for you?  Alternatively, you could put your `data_for_prediction` in a dataframe with the same feature names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you don't want to use `pandas.DataFrame` in your REST API endpoint, just don't train your model with the `DataFrame` but convert your data to a `numpy` array first:

```
>>> df
                    TEXT_1                TEXT_2    NUM_1  NUM_2
0  This is the first text.      The second text.  300.000   23.3
1  Here is the third text.  And the fourth text.    2.334   29.0
>>> df.to_numpy()
array([['This is the first text.', 'The second text.', 300.0, 23.3],
       ['Here is the third text.', 'And the fourth text.', 2.334, 29.0]],
      dtype=object)
```

Then, make changes in how you define the model. I'd suggest to combine preprocessing and predicting steps using `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` into a single model like this:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

model = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('transformer', ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ('TEXT_1', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', stop_words='english'), 0),
            ('TEXT_2', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', stop_words='english'), 1),
        ],
        remainder='passthrough',
    )),
    ('predictor', RandomForestClassifier()),
])
```

Note, here we are using indices instead of names to reference texts when defining transformers for the `ColumnTransformer` instance. Once we've transformed the initial `DataFrame` to a `numpy` array, the `TEXT_1` feature is located at `0`, and the `TEXT_2` at `1` in a data row. Here is how you can use the model:

```
from joblib import dump, load

X = df.to_numpy()
model.fit(X, y)
dump(model, 'model.joblib')

...

model = load('model.joblib')
results = model.predict(data)
```

As a result, you don't have to convert your incoming data to the `DataFrame` in order to make a prediction.

Answer (score 2):

The training data is a dataframe with the columns:

```
x_train.columns
```

the function `vectorizer.transform()` wants data in the same format, so assuming that

```
data_f_p = ["text that should be vectorized", 4,7,0]
```

corresponds to the same four columns as `x_train` you can turn it into a dataframe with

```
data_f_p = pd.DataFrame([data_f_p], columns=x_train.columns)
data_f_p = vectorizer.transform(data_f_p)
```

Comment: I have updated the question, so that you can have more info about my features. I have 4 features, 1 is textual ('text' is name of the df column) and other 3 are numerical.

Comment: I'm very confused what you're trying to do. Normally you'd feed *data* into the transform function: `vectorizer.transform(x_train)`  In your code it looks like you are trying to feed the *transformer* into the transform function. Have a look at the example in the sklearn docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html

Comment: I am doing that. I have data, that needs to be vectorized. I'm putting the data into vectorizer function in order to vectorize it, and then Im passing that data to model.predict.

Comment: ok, maybe now I'm getting it - see revised answer. Does this work?

Comment: Perhaps a better option might be `data_f_p = pd.DataFrame([data_f_p], columns=vectorizer.feature_names_in_)`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using pandas?
My final/saved model should be loaded in API, so api will take text as an input.
Since I transformed my columns and I specified name of the column that should be transformed, now I'm facing the issue with inputing text for prediction. Because inputed text do not have column name, its just a string.

Comment: I don't see the problem: `input = 'this is my string'`, `data_f_p = pd.DataFrame([[input, 4,7,0]], columns=x_train.columns)`, `data_f_p = vectorizer.transform(data_f_p)` You have 4 features, the string and 3 integers, that's why you use the sklearn vectorizer and pandas. And it's easy enough to extract the result string(s) from the dataframe using `.loc` and `.iloc`